# Inline verbatim with line breaks, colored font and highlighting

Tags: color, verbatim, highlighting

I'd like to be able to use *inline* *verbatim* text with the following features:

1. *Line breaks*, as provided for example by package `spverbatim`,  command `\spverb`;
2. *Colored font*, as provide by package `color`;
3. *Highlighting* (text with colored background), like `soul`'s package `\hl` command.

By "inline" I mean that the verbatim part is within the normal text (not an environment with its own paragraph), and by "verbatim" I mean that special symbols like `\`, `_` etc are not be interpreted by LaTeX.

What I'd like to achieve looks like this (using blue as font color and grey as highlighting color), but it should allow a line break if the verbatim part requires one.

[image]

I have tried packages `color`,  `newverbs`,  `spverbatim` and `soul`, but I haven't been able to combine all the above features. The closest I've got is:

- Tweaking `spverbatim`'s definition of `spverb` to include colored font. That way I get features 1 and 2, but not 3:

  ```
  \gdef\myVerb{%
    \bgroup
    \color{fgColor}%
    \let\spverb@ve=\verb@egroup
    \def\verb@egroup{\spverb@ve\egroup}%
    \def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}%
    \verb
  }
  ```

  Apparently `\myVerb` defined this way can't be chained with `soul`'s package `hl` to use `\hl{\myVerb{verbatim text}}` (LaTeX complains `LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`). Is there any way to combine them? For example, is there something analogous to `\hl` that can be added after `\color{fgColor}` in the code above to achieve highlighting?
- Using the `newverbs` package to define

  ```
  \newverbcommand{\myVerb}
  {\color{fgColor}\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}}
  {\end{lrbox}\colorbox{bgColor}{\usebox{\verbbox}}}
  ```

  This produces the font colored in `fgColor` and the highlighting with `bgColor`, so I get 2 and 3; but not 1: it doesn't allow line breaks. I guess that's because of `lrbox` or `\colorbox`,  but I don't know how to modify this to allow line breaks. Is there any way to do it?
- I can of course use

  ```
  \newcommand{\myVerb}[1]{{\ttfamily\color{fgcolor}{\hl{#1}}}}
  ```

  with `hl` as per `soul` package. With this I get 1, 2 and 3 but it's not verbatim, so I have to escape all special characters.

So, is there any way to achieve what I want? Either by solving what's missing in any of the above approaches, or by using a different approach? Perhaps there's a package that supports all the features I want off the shelf?

Answer (score 4):

While not exactly what the OP asks, it may suffice.  First, it uses `\detokenize`, not `verbatim`, which means 1) that braces `{}` must be balanced, 2) that the `%` symbol is still interpreted as a comment, 3) that a space is inserted after all detokenized macro names, and 4) Hash marks `#` are doubled in number.

Also, I just `\allowbreak` between words, using the `\fboxsep` of the colorbox to create the interword spaces.

EDITED to use `\ttfamily` for the `\mytokens` macro.

EDITED to fix line height, since the combination of a `\strut` and `\fboxsep` blew the allowed baselineskip budget.

Originally, I was not using interword space but allowed the `\fboxsep` to suffice.  But this caused margin issues, as nothing could stretch.  So, upon RE-EDIT, I insert a space of `0pt minus \fboxsep` between words, which seems to allow enough compression to address the margin issues, while still leaving enough space between words (otherwise `2\fboxsep`).

I also rearranged the `\grayspace` and `allowbreak`, upon RE-EDIT, so that a linebreak would not occur before trailing punctuation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mytokens[1]{\mytokenshelp#1 \relax\relax}
\def\mytokenshelp#1 #2\relax{\allowbreak\grayspace\tokenscolor{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else
 \mytokenshelp#2\relax\fi}
\newcommand\tokenscolor[1]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\textcolor{blue}{%
  \ttfamily\mystrut\smash{\detokenize{#1}}}}}
\def\mystrut{\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox+\fboxsep]{0pt}{%
 \dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-2\fboxsep}}
\def\grayspace{\hspace{0pt minus \fboxsep}}
\begin{document}
Here is my leading text
\mytokens{Fie Fi Fo Fum, I smell the $#@*& blood of an \Englishman.
I will continue this text to observe the margins. 
Fie Fi Fo Fum, I smell the \textbf{blood} of an Englishman.}
and my trailing text. And here is more text to find where the margin end
really should be.

Standard MATLAB formats are allowed, such as \mytokens{1.2}, \mytokens{-.2i},
\mytokens{1.}, \mytokens{-1.2e3}, \mytokens{+.2E-3j}.  \mytokens{i} and 
\mytokens{j} denote...
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

In response to a comment request, here is a version that takes the background color as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mytokens[2][gray!20]{\mytokenshelp{#1}#2 \relax\relax}
\def\mytokenshelp#1#2 #3\relax{\allowbreak\grayspace\tokenscolor[#1]{#2}\ifx\relax#3\else
 \mytokenshelp{#1}#3\relax\fi}
\newcommand\tokenscolor[2][gray!20]{\colorbox{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{%
  \ttfamily\mystrut\smash{\detokenize{#2}}}}}
\def\mystrut{\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox+\fboxsep]{0pt}{%
 \dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-2\fboxsep}}
\def\grayspace{\hspace{0pt minus \fboxsep}}
\begin{document}
Here is my leading text
\mytokens{Fie Fi Fo Fum, I smell the $#@*& blood of an \Englishman.
I will continue this text to observe the margins. 
Fie Fi Fo Fum, I smell the \textbf{blood} of an Englishman.}
and my trailing text. And here is more text to find where the margin end
really should be.

Standard MATLAB formats are allowed, such as \mytokens{1.2}, 
  \mytokens{-.2i}, \mytokens[red!40]{1.}, \mytokens{-1.2e3}, 
  \mytokens{+.2E-3j}.  \mytokens[cyan!30]{i} and 
  \mytokens[green!20]{j} denote...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do what I need, except that my verbatim text may contain non-balanced `{}`. It may also contain \, which produce an extra space if I understood correctly; but that's less of an issue for me

Comment: Hm, it looks like the `#` gets duplicated... Do you think my first approach could be modified to include something next to `\color{fgColor}` to realize the gray background in addition to the colored font?

Comment: @LuisMendo Apparently, the double `#` seems to be a function of `\detokenize`, of which I had been previously unaware.  I will have to add that as item 4 in the 1st paragraph list.  As to your other question, I am not sure how to do that, but I will give it more thought.

Comment: I ended up writing a program to transform for example `\myVerb+abc$\+` into `\myVerb{abc\$\textbackslash }` (that is, escape characters and use `{}` as delimiters). That way I can dispose of verbatim and use `\newcommand{\myVerb}[1]{{\ttfamily\color{fgcolor}{\hl{#1}}}}` (the third "solution" in my question). Not ideal but it works; I only need to pass my program on the tex file to do the transformation prior to compiling. So I no longer need a solution. However, I'm leaving the question here in case someone can solve the problem; I think it would be interesting to have an actual solution

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm glad you found a workaround.  If so inclined, you can always post your approach as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've just done so. Perhaps it will be of benefit to someone in the future

Comment: Could it be possible to have the background color as a optional parameter of the macro ``mytokens``? I can't manage to do it with the ``\mytokenshelp`` macro...

Comment: @3isenHeim Please see the supplement to my answer.

Comment: @steven-b-segletes thanks for the edit, I missed the parenthesis that made it work (``\mytokenshelp{#1}#2``) ! :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments to [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273850/90222), I ended up writing a Matlab function to transform for example

```
\myVerb+abc$\+
```

into

```
\myVerb{abc\$\textbackslash }
```

that is, escape characters and use `{}` as delimiters. That way I can dispose of `verbatim` and use

```
\newcommand{\myVerb}[1]{{\ttfamily\color{fgcolor}{\hl{#1}}}}
```

i.e. the third "solution" in my question. It's not ideal but it works; I only need to run my Matlab function on the tex file to do the transformation before compiling with LaTeX.

This is the Matlab function I use.

```octave
function convert_myVerb(fileName)

% Converts \myVerb+...+ or \myVerb|...| into: \myVerb{...} with escaped characters

fid = fopen(fileName);
s = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);
s = char(s.');
ind = regexp(s, '(?<=\\myVerb).');
unique(s(ind)); % characters found after "\myVerb", as a check. I only used + and |
[ini, fin] = regexp(s, '\\myVerb([+|]).*?\1'); % all matching substrings
if isempty(ini)
    disp('Nothing needs to be converted. Converted file not written')
else
    disp([num2str(numel(fin)) ' substrings identified for conversion'])
    y = s(1:ini(1)-1); % output. Initiallize
    % \# \$ \% \& \textbackslash{} \textasciicircum {}\_ \{ \} \textasciitilde{}
    ini(end+1) = numel(s)+1;
    for n = 1:numel(fin)
        t = regexprep(s(ini(n)+6:fin(n)-1), '\\', '\\textbackslash '); % This has
        % to go first, so that it won't convert \ introduced to escape other
        % characters. No {} here, because they would get converted into \{\} later
        t = regexprep(t, '[#$%&_{}]', '\\$0');
        t = regexprep(t, '\^', '\\textasciicircum{}');
        t = regexprep(t, '~', '\\textasciitilde{}');
        t = ['\myVerb{' t '}'];
        y = [y t s(fin(n)+1:ini(n+1)-1)];
    end
    fid = fopen(fileName, 'w');
    count = fwrite(fid, y);
    fclose(fid);
    if count
        disp('Converted file successfully written')
    end
end
```